# Draw svg on scroll depending on the position of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm using jQuery and the plugin drawsvg to reveal a svg on scroll like in this official demo  :
https://codepen.io/lcdsantos/pen/zvGQYB

I would like to obtain the same effect in different sections on the page :

- The page contains some sections ( undefined height )
- when scrolling    section 1 => reveal svg 1
- when scrolling section 2 => reveal svg 2

The code on the official demo is :

```
var $doc = $(document),
    $win = $(window),
    $svg = $('svg').drawsvg(),
    max = $doc.height() - $win.height();
$win.on('scroll', function() {
  var p = $win.scrollTop() / max;
  $svg.drawsvg('progress', p);
});
```

I've tried :

```
var max = $doc.height() - $win.height() - $('.section').height()  ;
```

Here's my codepen : https://codepen.io/PiccolinaEma/pen/wqpXea?editors=1111

But this is not the good way.

I've seen the waypoints plugin too but i don't understand how to combine them.
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Piccolina, did you solve this problem (same for me)? Waypoints, to my eyes, is not the right idea. Your idea doing a math calculation is the right way. But this depends on how the plugin handles the “progress” variable, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'clientHeight()' (JavaScript navite method).

Comment: The problem is not really the height but how to implement drawsvg.js on scroll of different sections ( and not of the window like the demo is showing ). To get the height of section i can use $('.my-element').height().